# Using ImageMagick I need to splice half of two images into a new image

Tags: machine-learning, imagemagick, keras

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this, since I need to create a script that will complete this task for about 3000 image files. So, I have two sets of images and I want to create two more sets. The object is to take the left vertical half of image A and combine it with the right half of image B, creating set AB. I will also need to do the opposite and create set BA, which would be the forth set. I need to do this in a way such that it continues the naming convention for the files, which have names like name.001.jpg. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your own attempts, sample images and desired results.

Comment: You have not explained if the two sets are in different folders, but have the same names? Is that correct? If not please clarify how to maintain the "same" name. This likely will need scripting. So what is your ImageMagick version and platform/OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do that in ImageMagick Unix syntax for two images.

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

```
convert logo.jpg logo_b5.jpg -crop 50x100% \( -clone 0,3 +append +write logo_A.jpg \) \( -clone 2,1 +append +write logo_B.jpg \) null:
```

logo_A.jpg

[image]

logo_B.jpg

[image]

Please explain where your two sets of data are stored and how they are named. For multiple pairs of images, you will need to write a loop assuming you have each set with the same name in two different folders. But you need to say what OS you are using since Windows bat scripting is different from Unix shell scripting.

Comment: Ubuntu, I actually have everything figured out now. With one exception. When I try to +append the two sides together I get an error that the height or width has been exceeded. Any ideas there? Ex. convert a.jpg b.jpg +append ab.jpg

Comment: How big are the two images in width and height? Is this on your desktop or via PHP exec()? What is your exact version of ImageMagick

Comment: ImageMagick Version 6.9.7-4, just from normal file system. I resized the images to 250x250 pixels. Cropped to 125x250, so now when I +append it 2 it should make a new 250x250. At least if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Does that work or do you still get the same error message?  Append does not care how big the two images are. They can be of different sizes.

Comment: That is when I get the error. I even tried montage and got the same error.

Comment: Did you try my exact command above with my images? Are you on Windows or Unix? If windows, then remove the \ escapes. Does my command and images work for your version of ImageMagick?

Comment: I don't see where your exact syntax is, but I just tried it on my Windows 10 work computer and it works fine. So there must be something wrong with the install on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: OK, I got a better error message with Windows.Since I'm using a wildcard to run through the images the +append seems to be trying to take the whole directory at once and append it. Which is way to many pixels and not what I want. So that leaves me with the problem of how to step through the images and append using a script.

Comment: I could show you how to do that in Unix bash shell scripting, but I do not know Windows batch scripting. Sorry.

Comment: It is all good, that I knew how to do just had to refresh myself on. Got everything completed the way I wanted it now. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: If my suggestions were of help, please consider up-voting my post.

Comment: I would but I'm 2 rep short. :(